# How do I exclude a directory by name using find?

Tags: bash, find

I have a lot of directories on my system, with a structure looking like this:

```
\-----data
       \------- 001abc
       \------- 002abc
       \------- 003abc
       \------- 004abc
       \------- 005abc
       \ ....
```

When I want find a certain directory, I just type `find . -iname "002abc*"` but how can I find a directory excluding certain name matches?

Something like this in MySQL `select * from folder where filename != '0021bc'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `!` in a `find` command to negate (invert) the option following after. In your case:

```
find . ! -iname "002abc*"
```

and optionally, only matching folders:

```
find . ! -iname "002abc*" -type d
```

will list all folders except the ones named matching the pattern `002abc*`.

The `!` can be problematic in shell scripting sometimes, so [as Flimm pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243469/how-do-i-exclude-a-directory-by-name-using-find#comment301521_243474), the `-not` parameter is a very useful synonym to it.

Comment: A synonym of `!` is `-not`, like this: `find . -not -iname "002abc*"`

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, you can combine the flags to produce something like: ``find -L . -name '*.php' ! -name 'vendor/*.php' -print0`` which will find all php files that are NOT inside a vendor folder

Answer (score 1):

You can find "all" folders and then select out the one you don't want with `grep -v` (or egrep for that matter)

```
find . -iname "abc*" | grep -v 002
```

If you want to select out more than one name, you can use sequential grep -v or one egrep statement.

```
find . -iname "abc*" | grep -v 002 | grep -v 003
```

or

```
find . -iname "abc*" | egrep -v "002|003"
```

You'll have to tune it to what you want, and I'm happy to iterate. If you read the man page for find, you'll find lots of flags to sort for files and folders, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
find -name 0021bc -prune -o -print
```